# Paste a range from Excel into certain slide of Powerpoint Template using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've spent a good few hours looking at various suggested solutions to my problem but cannot find anything that seems to do the job, or more likely, my grasp of VBA is understanding my ability to make sense of the online solutions. As such, I'm hoping one of you kind folk can help me resolve things.

I have an Excel Worksheet open that contains a small amount of data (Headings and numbers etc.)

I want to copy this range and paste it (not as a picture, I want to be able to format it within powerpoint if necessary) on a particular slide (slide 2) in a Powerpoint template I have already created.

My VBA correctly opens up a new presentation based on the template using the following code:

```
    'Opens a PowerPoint Document from Excel

Dim objPPT As Object

Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
objPPT.Visible = True

'Change the directory path and file name to the location
'of your document

objPPT.Presentations.Open "C:\Users\Colin\Dropbox (Edge45)\Edge45 Team Folder\Edge45 Company Documents\Templates\Powerpoint Templates\Edge45 Audit Template Macro.potm", Untitled:=msoTrue
```

However, this is where I get stuck - I don't know how to paste the Excel tabular data into the correct slide once the presentation is open. My data is in range A1:D16

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this one. I have assigned Excel worksheet to one variable (`XLws`) and PowerPoint slide to another (`PPslide`). You can Copy/Paste objects between them.

Btw, you need to have PowerPoint Library enabled. If you don't, in your VBA project go to **Tools -> References -> Microsoft PowerPoint 15.0 Object Library**.

```
Sub PPcopy()
Dim PPapp As PowerPoint.Application, PPpres As PowerPoint.Presentation, PPslide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim XLws As Worksheet

    Set XLws = ActiveSheet
    Set PPapp = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set PPpres = PPapp.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\Colin\Dropbox (Edge45)\Edge45 Team Folder\Edge45 Company Documents\Templates\Powerpoint Templates\Edge45 Audit Template Macro.potm")
    PPapp.Visible = True
    Set PPslide = PPpres.Slides(2)
    XLws.Range("A1:D16").Copy
    PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: That's brilliant @Limak, however, the pasted object I cannot select individual cells and format as necessary. I assume this is to do with how the paste type is working - What would I need to change it to in the VBA code to make it paste so I can manipulate the contents of the cells?

Comment: The method I have posted uses formatting form source workbook. So, why not manipulate your table in Excel, and then paste it to PowerPoint, instead of edit Excel object inside PowerPoint? It's gonna be much more complicated, or even impossible.

Comment: Hi, yes, that is one solution but some of the cells I do need to be able to click into once in powerpoint. If I copy some cells in Excel and then paste special "Keep Source Formatting (K)" once in powerpoint, I get an editable table, I can change cell spacing, insert new rows etc. If I can do it manually, surely it can be done using VBA?

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure, VBA is working great inside this Excel sandbox and nowhere else. Once you paste table inside PowerPoint it is not some Excel cells, but PowerPoint shape. To be honest with you, I have no idea how to manipulate such shapes, inside another program. It is another topic, worth creating another post.

Comment: And googling ofc ;)